# Bind url into a ref tag from external variable

Tags: c#, html, tags, href

I have the following HTML code:

```
var textBody1 = "My URL";
var url = "http://www.google.co.il";
var html = "<table width = '100%'><tr><td align='left' style=font-family:'Arial'>"
                + "<a href='http://www.google.co.il' target='blank'>" + textBody1 + "</a>"
                + "</td></tr></table>";
```

The var `textBody1` is concatenated to the html tags, so that the final html page will show its value. 
My challenge is to implement the same thing,
this time for the `url` variable.
Unfortunately I couldn't find the right way to bind the parameter into a middle of a tag. 
Can anyone help me please? 
Tali.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what you mean by adding in middle of the tag?

Is that some thing adding href value using URL ' "<a href='"+url+"' target='blank'>" + textBody1 + "</a>"' something like this?

Comment: @RajeeshMadambat This is exacly what I was looking for. Thank you so much !!